# How does below comparator function works in c++?

Tags: c++

```
bool comp(int a,int b){

    if ((a > 0 && b > 0) || (a < 0 && b < 0))
        return false;

    if ((a > 0) && (b < 0))
        return false;
}
```

To a given array, which contains positive and negative integers, the above function is useful to rearrange the array such that, negative integers followed by positive integers and it preserves the order of elements.

Example:

```
int arr [] = {1,2,-3,-1}, n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);

sort(arr,arr+n, comp);

output : {-3,-1,1,2}
```

But I am unable to understand how it is working, Could someone explain ?

Comment: the comp function pointer is passed to the sort function so that it knows how to sort the integers, say you wanted to sort them from largest to smallest instead, you could write the comp function differently

Comment: That can't be the full `comp` function you're showing. Are you missing a default `return true;`?

Comment: What do you mean by preserving the order of the elements? The point of sorting is, is to change the order of the elements according to some sorting scheme.

Comment: *"the above function is useful to rearrange the array such that, negative integers followed by positive integers and it preserves the order of elements"* Are you looking fo `std::stable_partition`?

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Good point. I've wiki'd my answer.

Comment: yeah, consider there is "return true" at the end of  "comp"  function but it is not effecting anything.

Comment: @Philipp, purpose of comp function is to move all the negative integers to starting of the array followed by all positive integers(not sort the array). like if input is  {4, 1 , -1, -3, -2} then output should be {-1, -3, -2, 4, 1}.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your assertions are incorrect on two counts:

1. `std::sort` is *not* guaranteed to preserve the order of elements that don't need sorting, if you get my meaning.
2. The behaviour of your `comp` function is *undefined* as it doesn't have an explicit `return` value on all control paths.

One remedy is to use `std::stable_sort` which will preserve the order of elements as best it can. The comparator function can be adjusted such that it's `true` if the first argument is negative and the second is positive (let's define 0 to be positive):

```
bool comp(int a, int b){
    return a < 0 && b >= 0;
}
```

Another remedy is to use `std::stable_partition`.

Comment: yeah, consider there is "return true" at the end of  "comp"  function but it is not effecting anything  and my question was,how "comp" function is helping to preserve the order and rearranging the elements ?

Comment: @kranti, actually, simple `std::stable_partition(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [](int i){return i < 0; })` should work better and have no bugs. KISS rule in action.

Answer (score 0):

> But I am unable to understand how it is working, Could someone explain ?

I try to explain how it's supposed to work, but actually, it does not work :)

```
bool comp(int a, int b) {

    if((a > 0 && b > 0) || (a < 0 && b < 0))
        return false;

    if((a > 0) && (b < 0))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

This code *tries* to compare signs: checking whether sign of `a` is "less" than sign of `b`. Assuming that negative is "less" than positive. So, sign of -1 is less than sign of 1, and sign of -3 is not less than sign of -1.

The problem here is that comparator should always conform with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings.

In short, strict weak ordering is: for any `a` and `b`, only one condition is true: `a < b`, or `b < a`, or `b == a`. There should be no case when more of one condition is true.

When strict weak ordering is violated in production code, very bad things will happen: overtimes, failed deadlines, and even worse.

Your sort() will fail on this array: `{ 1, 0, 2, 0, -3, 0,-1 }` because strict weak ordering is violated: both `comp(-1, 0)` is true and `comp(0, -1)` is true.